# Evaluating the integral ${\int_0^{1000} e^{x-[x]}dx}$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate the integral:
>
> $${\int_0^{1000} e^{x-[x]}dx}$$

This is what I have tried to do:
$$\int_0^{1000} e^{x-[x]} dx = 1000 \times \int_0^1 e^{x-[x]} dx.$$

Next, $1000 \times {1.(1-1)} = 0$.

The given answer is ${1000(e-1)}$ but I am getting $0$. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: When you use upper or lower subscripts, you must use {} to enclose numbers with more than one digit...

Comment: I know. But I am using it on a mobile phone,so missed it!! :)

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_0^1e^{x-[x]}dx =\int_0^1e^{x }dx=e-1. $$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^{1000}e^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{999}\int_k^{k+1}e^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{999}\int_k^{k+1}e^{x-k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{999}e^{x-k}\big|_k^{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{999}(e-1)=1000(e-1)$$